deploy and install magento for docker compose
When trying to run <docker compose run --rm deploy cloud-deploy> I get a 131 error "missing crypt key for installing magento"
I was under the impression that while running this command to deploy that it would create a crypt key.
Any thoughts or ideas?
Thanks
